# Rendering innerHTML content from API with angular universal SSR

Tags: angular, innerhtml, angular-universal

I currently have a SPA Angular 8 App that gets html content from an API and renders it using the innerHTML attribute in the html component.

I'm in the process of converting this to Angular Universal for SSR (To make the project more SEO friendly) but this doesn't seem to be working.

Can Angular Universal pull in HTML from a restful API and render it server side?

HTML:

`<div [innerHtml]="generic.htmlContent | sanitize"></div`>

SERVICE:

```
get(route: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<IGeneric>(`${environment.api.url}/api/generic/get?=${route}`)
      .pipe(retry(1));
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
this.genericService.get(url).subscribe(g => {
     this.generic = g;
},
```

Thanks

Comment: try adding ```content type: "text/plain"``` in http request header

Comment: Hi Santosh - thanks for your response. Should the above be achievable using SSR? And is it going to be worth it in terms of performance? Just wanted to know before I begin implementing/converting to Angular Universal.

Comment: Does your code work without SSR? If it does, it shou work with SSR as well. This will put more load on the server, but you'll have SEO friendly content